# Jenkins job with multiple dynamic parameters

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Here is my requirement.

I want to use the Jenkins for packaging multiple zip files.

We have an artifactory with **repo A** and **repo B** -- Each one of them have multiple zip files. I have the api's to list the files of a repo

In Jenkins, I want to create a parameterized job where 1st parameter should be able to populate list of zip files from **Repo A** and 2nd parameter should be able to populate list of zip files from **Repo B** + In 2nd parameter i should be able to select multiple zip files populated from **Repo B**

Can you please suggest a better way to do this.

Comment: Please specify what you mean. It's a little unclear what you mean by the `parameters`, whether they will be set in the Jenkins GUI or it is just parameter for pipilene logic

Comment: I want to do a parameterized job. the parameters is kind of choice parameter where the parameters are populated dynamically based on the files in artifactory repo

Answer (score 0):

Try something like it:

```groovy
List<String> files = populate()
doSomething(files)

List<String> populate() {
     List<String> files = ''
     if (JOB_PARAMETER == 'repoA') {
         files.add(yourApiCall())
     } //similarly for another
     return files
}
```

`JOB_PARAMETER` is a parameter in your Jenkins job

Comment: FYI.. I found a plugin "Active choice plugin" in jenkins. This has all the functionality i mentioned. Still struggling to print elements in dropdown. Do you mind giving a simple groovy script to retrun 1 to 10 values

Comment: to return from where?

Comment: Here is my observation— for this active choice plugin we need to write groovy script for any parameters - it’s kind of different . If you do println it errors out - we need to return values - if you can please look at active choice plugin you can better understand - I need help to call artifactory api and return values to drop down of this plugin - any help is appreciated

Comment: I know Active choice parameter plugin) I didn't quite understand what you want) Create `Active Choices parameter` (repoName) and `Active choice reactive parameter`. In first select `Groovy Script` and put there `['Repo A',  'Repo B']`. In second put something like:
    `res = ''
     if ( repoName== 'Repo A') {
         res = callYourApi()
    }
    return res`. `res` must be a listt. And in `Referenced parameters` specify `repoName`

Comment: Hello FCh -- My requirement is very simple. Populate artifacts from artifactory repo to a choice parameter in jenkins dynamically. i.e, when i add any new artifacts in artifactory - it should populate in jenkins parameter